# Creating an AWS Quicksight datasource from an Excel file through Java API

Tags: java, excel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

I am currently generating an Excel file (single sheet) on a spring boot server that I want to use as a dataset in Quicksight by uploading it through the AWS/Quicksight Java API. Currently, my method for doing so is converting the Excel file to a CSV on the server, uploading the CSV file with a generated manifest file to an S3 bucket, and then using the manifest file to upload the CSV file as a datasource from S3.

The manifest file only takes CSV, TSV, ELF, CLF, and JSON as the [file format options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-manifest-file-format.html) for uploading to Quicksight. Is there another option for uploading an Excel file for use as a datasource without file conversions or that is more straightforward?

The Quicksight UI has the option to upload a sheet from an XLSX file as a dataset, but this doesn't seem as straightforward when automating dataset creation through the API.

Comment: YOu state "Currently, my method for doing so is converting the Excel file to a CSV on the server, uploading the CSV file with a generated manifest file to an S3 bucket, and then using the manifest file to upload the CSV file as a datasource from S3." How are you doing this. Did you build a workflow using AWS Step functions for example?

Comment: @smac2020 I put the CSV and manifest files in an S3 bucket by using the AmazonS3ClientBuilder and the putObject method in the AWS S3 API on the server. The datasource is created by calling the createDataSource method with the proper parameters, including the manifest file location in S3